# Java version control

Tags: java, api, version-control, version, docx

I am using docx4j to load, manipulate and save Word files. Everything works perfectly but there is one thing i don't know how to implement it.
What I want is something like a version control - that means if you save a document it shall be possible to recover a earlier version of this document (e.g. by saving only the delta). Maybe you can describe it that is should be something like SVN or Git where you can go back to an earlier version of your files.
The problem is that i do not know any possibility to realize that. So I hope that anyone of you can help me. It would be fine if anyone at least know a package or something else that can do this with files in general and not especially with the docx Files.
Thanks for your help!

Edit: I am sorry that my question was imprecise. This was my first post here, in future i will improve ;)

Comment: why don't you want to use SVN or Git?

Comment: I really don't get why you made a post asking for version control then ruled out using version control.

Comment: is there a api that interacts with svn from java? because the user who saves the docx files should not notice what happens in background. if there is something that makes the handling with svn that easy like the sql handling in java i would be very charmed.

Comment: Because he didn't know there is a Git for Java. Don't be so hard on people.

Comment: I linked JGit in my answer.  It works well and is not particularly difficult to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I think you should use Git for this, I found a Java API called [JavaGit](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/), so you can have easy access the repository.
With Git you can have a local repository where you can commit files and switch versions. If you need it you could also push and pull the data to a remote location.</s>

Better use [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) like Gian said!

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. I know git, but i did not think so simply at the moment when asking the question here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JavaGit is deprecated in favour of JGit these days. Notice the last update was an alpha release in 2008.

Comment: Yes you are right, he should use JGit instead like you posted, but can't remove this answer because it's accepted.

Answer (score 6):

[JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) is a Java implementation of Git that will work with few dependencies.  Similar libraries exist for SVN and CVS.  Home-brewing a version control system is almost certainly a terrible idea, given the existence of good-quality solutions!

Comment: But remember Git doesn't actually do deltas. It's a complete snapshot every time.

Comment: That doesn't sound *quite* accurate.  It doesn't do per-file deltas, but it does per-tree deltas, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like some pure java implementatoin for document versioning, maybe you could go for: [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)

Similar questions have been already asked before. The 1.st answer (marked as correct one) on this question goes for Jackrabbit as well: Using a version control system as a data backend

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible way would be to use tools `diff` and `patch`. They were used as a core of CVS. I assume that you would like to run your application in Windows where they are not preinstalled. I don't know whether it would be easy / comfortable to use windows versions of this tools but you can always try to write similiar functionality on your own. Here you can find very good tutorial about finding differences between files and patching them: http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2012/09/18/introduction-using-diff-and-patch/ When you know the functionality it's quite easy to write something similiar on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a tricky thing to implement yourself, so I wouldn't recommend it.

I don't know much about your environment, but if you are able to use an off-the-shelf versioning repository, you'll save yourself much grief.  You can try to use Git or SVN directly, which may be the simplest solution for your use case.

Since you're talking about MS Office files, however, you may be implementing some form of enterprise document management tool.  In this case, the JCR specification is designed to provide access to files in a repository, with versioning and other metadata features.  Here's the [specification](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/index.html).

The [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org) project provides an open source implementation of this spec, as does the developers version of [Alfresco](https://developer.alfresco.com).

Picking the right solution will really depend on what your users are trying to do with these files, what your deployment environment looks like (don't try to host Git on Windows, k?), and  how custom your current codebase is (standard Servlet container?  Java EE?  home-rolled?).

Good luck!

Comment: Following the JCR train of thought, it would be remiss not to mention CMIS, which followed it, and WebDAV/DeltaV (one of several predecessors).